# Duplicate class com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture found in modules jetified-guava-26.0-android.jar

Tags: java, android, firebase

I got errors

Duplicate class com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture found in modules jetified-guava-26.0-android.jar (com.google.guava:guava:26.0-android) and jetified-listenablefuture-1.0.jar (com.google.guava:listenablefuture:1.0)

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.

After update

> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'

to

> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'

and gradle 5.4.1 to 5.6.4

Problem solved when downgrade

> implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.4.1'

to

> implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.4.0'

Is this a bug of firebase/firestore?

Comment: The Firebase Android release notes don't acknowledge that 21.4.1 is the latest version.  It shows 21.4.0 as the latest.  https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android

Comment: But if you think there is a bug you should file an issue on the Firebase Android SDK GitHub.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/

Comment: Same problem witn the newer version ( 21.4.2), downgraded to 21.4.0 and worked

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think part of the issue is that Android Studio (or maybe the Gradle Plugin, however that is handled) is recommending to update the version of the Firestore dependency to 21.4.1 (likely depends on the order of repositories in your build.gradle - not sure on that). And yes, it seems that 21.4.1 causes the issue.

[image: Gradle upgrade recommendation for Firestore lib to 21.4.1]

So yeah, just ignore that recommendation and leave it at 21.4.0. Also...

1. [Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart) show 21.4.0 as the correct version.
2. [MVN Repository shows 21.4.1](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.firebase/firebase-firestore) as the latest release.
3. [Google Maven Repo](https://maven.google.com/web/index.html) also lists 21.4.1 as the latest release.

Comment: I confirm. Problem solved after downgrading to 21.4.0. Thank you!

Answer (score 27):

I am using latest version of firebase firestore i.e.

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.4.3'
```

and adding this line worked for me:

```
implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:27.0.1-android'
```

Answer (score 26):

After updating Firebase, I encountered this issue as well.

Fix the conflict by adding the following package to your `build.gradle`

```
implementation 'com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava'
```

Comment: This worked a treat when hitting this issue with the FlutterFire libs.

Comment: Unbelievable.. it worked!

Answer (score 3):

For the one who does not find a solution, this helped me.
Add this dependency in your app/build.gradle file.

implementation "com.google.guava:listenablefuture:9999.0-empty-to-avoid-conflict-with-guava"

Source:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1320#issuecomment-601159166

Answer (score 2):

implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:28.2-android'

add this to your gradle and you're good to go

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of firestore is:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.4.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have not added firestore as a dependency and still getting this error add below dependency to gradle

```
implementation group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '27.0.1-android'
```

Answer (score 0):

I just added

`implementation group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '27.0.1-android'`

into my dependencies.